# which best option to store key value pair in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-hive, flutter-secure-storage

which plugin should I use to save data as key-value pair and some of them will be serialized objects? and is there are any differences in performance?

[share prefrences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences),
[flutter secure storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage)  or
[hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive)

Comment: Opinion based questions are Off Topic in StackOverFlow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flutter_secure_storage` is stored with `aes` encryption and it saved as same `shared_preefrences` does but there is better option available with `same security` but with high performance `hive`.

performance difference can be shown as below,

> for 1000 read iterations
>
> [image]

> 1000 write iterations
>
> [image]